# React I couldn't get the Price Popup window to close

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building the React application and I am unable to close the Price Popup window. I tried everything all day yesterday but couldn't solve this problem. Can anyone help me find the error, please?

What I am attempting to do is when you click on the `Price` button in each Security list, the Popup window open up with Price list. You can enter a new price to the list. Then when you click on `Close` button, the window close and the security list with price list in each security is updated.

You can check out my React application at https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kikidesignnet/caissa.

Comment: Share the code. The link is down.

Comment: @JothamArdel the link is not broken to me ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code logic, your `price` button is suppose to open another component `<PriceForm>` but you didn't pass any `toggle` method to close it, so you just to need to pass the `togglePricePopup` as a prop (I called it `onClose`) then call it inside your `handleFormSubmit`:

**SingleSecuritybox/index.js**

```js
{this.state.showPricePopup ? (
  <PriceForm
    pricelist={this.props.price}
    editCurrentPrice={this.editCurrentPrice}
    onClose={this.togglePricePopup} // new prop
  />
) : null}
```

**PriceForm/index.js**

```js
handleFormSubmit = e => {
  // prevents page refreshes on submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // code...

  // passed prop from SingleSecuritybox
  this.props.onClose();
};
```

**[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-voice-0z68q)**

Comment: Thanks so much! I would like to ask you one more thing if you don't mind. I noticed that when I add a new price in the Price Popup window and then close it but rechecked the Price Popup window again. The new price that I entered disappeared. I couldn't figure out how to solve it. I'm trying to pass it up to App.js as one developer suggested. I have built a .json file called securities and the price list is in each security.

Comment: Hi @KristinaBressler I'm glad that i could help. Actually you can't because the prices list is comping from `securities.json` file and you can't access it from the browser to update. I'd suggested to use a database like mongodb or firebase or even your localStorage because eventually you'll anyway.

Comment: Hi I'm sorry. I noticed that when I remove the  `this.props.onClose();` from `handleFormSubmit` I was able to submit the data from `PriceForm` to `SingleSecurityBox`. but if I add `this.props.onClose();` then I cannot submit any data....